# How to see the output size of a layer in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to TensorFlow and currently writing my first CNN using the library. Previously I have used keras and to check the output dimensions of layers used the model.summary() function. 
How do I check the output dimensions of layers in TensorFlow ? This is my model :

```
generator(input, random_dim, is_train, reuse=False):
    c4, c8, c16, c32, c64 = 512, 256, 128, 64, 32 # no of nodes in each conv2d layer
    s4 = 4
    output_dim = CHANNEL  # B/W image for RGB channel = 3
    with tf.variable_scope('gen') as scope: 
        if reuse:
            scope.reuse_variables()
        w1 = tf.get_variable('w1', shape=[random_dim, s4 * s4 * c4], dtype=tf.float32,
                             initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02))
        b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', shape=[c4 * s4 * s4], dtype=tf.float32,
                             initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
        flat_conv1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(input, w1), b1, name='flat_conv1')

        conv1 = tf.reshape(flat_conv1, shape=[-1, s4, s4, c4], name='conv1')
        bn1 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv1, is_training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, decay = 0.9,  updates_collections=None, scope='bn1')
        act1 = tf.nn.relu(bn1, name='act1')
        # 8*8*256

        conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(act1, c8, kernel_size=[3, 3], strides=[2, 2], padding="SAME",
                                           kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                           name='conv2')
        bn2 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv2, is_training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, decay = 0.9,  updates_collections=None, scope='bn2')
        act2 = tf.nn.relu(bn2, name='act2')
        # 16*16*128
        conv3 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(act2, c16, kernel_size=[3, 3], strides=[2, 2], padding="SAME",
                                           kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                           name='conv3')
        bn3 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv3, is_training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, decay = 0.9,  updates_collections=None, scope='bn3')
        act3 = tf.nn.relu(bn3, name='act3')
        # 32*32*64
        conv4 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(act3, c32, kernel_size=[3, 3], strides=[2, 2], padding="SAME",
                                           kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                           name='conv4')
        bn4 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv4, is_training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, decay = 0.9,  updates_collections=None, scope='bn4')
        act4 = tf.nn.relu(bn4, name='act4')
        # 64*64*32
        conv5 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(act4, c64, kernel_size=[3, 3], strides=[2, 2], padding="SAME",
                                           kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                           name='conv5')
        bn5 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv5, is_training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, decay = 0.9,  updates_collections=None, scope='bn5')
        act5 = tf.nn.relu(bn5, name='act5')

        #128*128*3
        conv6 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(act5, output_dim, kernel_size=[3, 3], strides=[2, 2], padding="SAME",
                                           kernel_initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02),
                                           name='conv6')
        # bn6 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(conv6, is_training=is_train, epsilon=1e-5, decay = 0.9,  updates_collections=None, scope='bn6')

        #BATCH NORM IN EVERY LAYER EXCEPT LAST !
        act6 = tf.nn.tanh(conv6, name='act6')
        return act6
```

Using python 3

Comment: try `print(conv6.get_shape())`, where `conv6` is the tensor you are interested in.

Comment: @MaosiChen I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

At compile time (unkown dimensions will have `None` or `?` values):

```
a = ...  # Your tensor
print(a.shape.dims)
```

At runtime (unknown dimensions will be computed from input data):

```
sess = tf.Session()
a = ... # Your tensor
feed_dict = {...}  # Values required to compute a
shape_op = tf.shape(a)
shape_res = sess.run(shape_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
print(shape_res)
```

Cheers